# Just another infamous We're sorry, but something went wrong. in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm trying for my first time to load my app on heroku.

When I try `heroku run rake db:migrate` my terminal shows these migrations and then stops.

```
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
Migrating to DeviseCreateUsers (20121128151440)
Migrating to AddUsernameToUsers (20121129162857)
...
Migrating to AddWebsiteToEvents (20130108053401)
Migrating to AddCoverToUsers (20130108055101)
my-imac:pm diolor$
```

When I open the app I see the lovely We're sorry, but something went wrong. message like many people in here.

Anyone has an idea what might I have missed and I see this?
Btw in my local app I use Pow.

### Edit: my logs

```
2013-01-08T18:44:45+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by *@gmail.com
2013-01-08T18:44:49+00:00 heroku[run.1243]: Awaiting client
2013-01-08T18:44:49+00:00 heroku[run.1243]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-01-08T18:44:49+00:00 heroku[run.1243]: State changed from starting to up
2013-01-08T18:44:55+00:00 heroku[run.1243]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2013-01-08T18:44:56+00:00 heroku[run.1243]: Process exited with status 0
2013-01-08T18:44:56+00:00 heroku[run.1243]: State changed from up to complete
```

Comment: try running heroku logs and see what went wrong

Comment: @Nishant edited with logs

Comment: could you try with webrick.

Answer (score 1):

Write your console on your app directory

```
heroku logs -t
```

and go to your apps and run it. Copy and paste the logs here.